# What is the best way of checking the current user privileges on a particular table from another schema?

Tags: oracle, permissions

In my software, at runtime, I need to check if the connected user has the privileges on some tables, across 2 different schemas.
From what I found doing research, I came across these 2 views
ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD 
ALL_TAB_PRIVS
Should I use one of these views, or is there another better way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally came with this query that I use only if the connected user is different than the schema I want to check privileges on:

```
SELECT PRIVILEGE
FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD
WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'GN_VERSION'
AND OWNER = 'USER_A'
UNION ALL
SELECT PRIVILEGE
FROM SESSION_PRIVS
WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'SELECT ANY TABLE';
```

This checks the SELECT privilege on the table GN_VERSION on the USER_A schema

Answer (score 5):

[`ALL_TAB_PRIVS`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_2110.htm) is a superset of [`ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_2112.htm). You probably want `ALL_TAB_PRIVS` as it includes tables that the current user owns.

Comment: After some tests, ALL_TAB_PRIVS also returns the privileges the current user granted to other users. Even if the documentation says so, it does not include tables that the user own, that's why I prefer ALL_TAB_PRIVS_RECD

Comment: Neither view includes tables that the user owns unless there is an explicit grant - both show grants not permissions. You may like to do a `union` with `user_tables`?